# CFX_ImageCR3 | Unable to Load Library on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-Bit running ColdFusion 10 64 Bit

Tags: c++, dll, coldfusion, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

We are attempting to migrate our old web server to a new web server.  We are trying to install Effalre's CFX_ImageCR3 tag on our Windows Server 2008 R2 64 Bit server running ColdFusion 10 64-Bit.

We've installed the latest setup file from Efflare's website and have registered the CFX C++ Tag in the ColdFusion administrator just as the documentation describes, but when the code that uses the CFX_ImageCR3 tag executes, it says "Unable to load library."

After searching Google, one person recommended we run Dependency Walker to see what DLL's were missing.  On the new server, it says the following 'delay-load dependency module was not found' 
- GPSVC.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL
- MF.DLL
- MFPLAT.DLL
- MFREADWRITE.DLL
- WLANAPI.DLL

For comparison, I ran the same program on the old server on which that CFX tag is working.  It reported that GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL could not load, but the other ones could.

Both of the servers are running the same Operation Systems and the only difference is Cold Fusion 10.  Is it possible that I'm just missing some DLLs on the new server?  Could it be that it is not compatible with ColdFusion 10 64-Bit?  Can you load 32-bit DLL CFX C++ tags on a 64-bit install of CF?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution found.  It appears that the C++ CFX tax is 32 bit and is compatible with ColdFusion 64-bit version.  Effalre currently has a beta installer on their VIP download site, cfx_imagecr_3_service_beta_081030.exe, which is the Java tag.

This was a bit tricky to figure out at first, but once you install the beta make sure you follow these steps:

1. Install the beta installer to C:\efflare\ (Do not install to C:\Program Files (x86)!)
2. Start the windows service 'Efflare ImageCR 3 Service'
3. Open the CF Administrator then goto Java and JVM, in the ColdFusion Class Path add: {applicatino.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/lib,C:/Efflare/imagecr3.jar
4. Restart ColdFusion

NOTE: The class path if for the default ColdFusion 10 install.  The first path must point to the directory where you have a cfx.jar file.  If you get the error -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Exception com/allaire/cfx/CustomTag it is because the class path is not pointing to where the cfx.jar file is located at.